# Safe way to 'reshape' a branch's history

Tags: git

Often, when using git, I will make the mistake of rebasing or merging something that I didn't really want.  For example, say I have three commits that I initially don't want to show in the history, and one that I do, like `A-B-C-D`, where `D` is the commit that I want.  So I run

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

and I squash `A`, `B`, and `C`.  But then, later, I decide that I actually wanted to have two commits, because `A` was totally unrelated to the other three and the history would make more sense if it were on its own.  What I would do now is,

```
git reflog | grep 'rebase -i'
```

which would spit out some list that ends with

```
<someHash> HEAD@{<num>}: rebase -i (start): checkout HEAD~4
```

and I would then run

```
git checkout HEAD@{<num>+1}
git br -D <branchIWasWorkingOn>
git checkout -b <branchIWasWorkingOn>
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

and do exactly the same thing I did before, but `pick`ing commit `A` too this time.  This is really cumbersome, and requires deleting branches, which makes me nervous that this workflow isn't particularly safe.  My question is, is there a more secure way to rewrite history than this `reflog` & `branch deletion` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My favorite way to split commits if necessary is to simply `git reset --soft HEAD~1` which will bring all the changes of the last commit, in your case 4 merged commits, to the staging area. From there you can recommit them as you see fit. So the basic flow would be having commits like such `A-B-C-D`where `D` is multiple commits you'd like to break up. run `git reset --soft HEAD~1` and you'll have `A-B-C` with `D`'s changes in the staging area. Commit as many separate times as you'd like say two, and you'd have `A-B-C-E-F`.

Now thats great if the commit is at the top of your HEAD. But if you need to go back several commits, you'll still need to create a branch, `git reset --hard HEAD~n` to remove extra commits (don't worry they're safe on the other branch). Then run the `git reset --soft HEAD~1`. Once you've recommitted whatever you'd like, you can rebase your original branch off this branch to get to where you'd like to be.

I can't say its much cleaner than your method, might be a bit easier. For me its at least easier to visualize whats happening. That being said, if you're rewriting history, its going to be a bit messy. Just be sure you take your time and are mindful of whats getting deleted when.

*Also, as a nice side note, turns out even rebasing commits out of the branch doesn't make them go away. Git caches everything. So I'd deleted a commit I shouldn't have before, but because I knew the commit hash by scrolling up in terminal, I was able to cherry-pick it back into existence. So not all is lost when you delete something.*